# Where is a flaw in these logical implications?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, inequality

We have a theorem: If $a \le x < a + {\frac yn}$ for $y > 0$ and all natural $n \ge 1$ then $x = a$.

Suppose I derive that $a < x$ and $x < a + {\frac yn}$ for all $n \ge 1$. In other words $a < x < a + {\frac yn} \implies a \le x < a + {\frac yn}$. Then by the theorem I conclude that  $x = a$.

But I derived that $a < x$ previously. Where is an error? I guess it doesn't show that the theorem is wrong. Maybe the way I derived that $a < x$ was wrong.

Comment: How did you derived that $a<x$?

Comment: It is a made up situation. Maybe I just assumed that $a < x$.

Comment: Why would you want to assume that $a<x$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you arrive at a contradiction, you should become suspicious. In fact it is not possible to have $x<a+\frac yn$ for all $n$ and $x>a$ at the same time. So if you actually derived $x<a+\frac yn$ for all $n$ and $x>a$ you either made some mistake in the derivaion, or you based your derivation on  some *hypothesis*; inthat case, that hypothesis must be wrong. - This is just as if you dereive $1=0$ from some hypothesis, then that hypothesis is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Known fact: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{y}{n} = 0.$ So, use Squeeze theorem for sequences.

If you suppose that $a<x$ then:
$$0<x-a < \frac{y}{n}$$
$$\Longrightarrow n(x-a) < y$$
and, by archimedian property of the real numbers, this is a contradiction.
Therefore, $a\leq x$.

Comment: We don't use limits at this stage in the book on Calculus. Only some properties of real numbers like Archimedean property.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you (unknowingly) assumed two hypotheses that were directly contradictory. Indeed, the following are equivalent for any real numbers $a$ and $x$:

- $x\le a.$
- For all $y>0$ and all natural $n\ge1,$ we have $x<a+\frac yn.$

The proof is fairly simple. For the one implication, note that if $y>0$ and $n\ge 1,$ then $\frac yn>0,$ so $x\le a$ implies that $x\le a<a+\frac yn$ for all such $y$ and $n.$

For the other implication, suppose that $x>a.$ Then $x-a>0.$ Take $y=1,$ so that $y>0.$ By Archimedean property, $\frac y{x-a}=\frac1{x-a}$ is *not* an upper bound of the natural numbers, and so there exists some natural $n\ge1$ such that $$n>\frac y{x-a}.$$ Since $n$ and $x-a$ are both positive, then it follows that $$x-a>\frac yn,$$ and so $$x>a+\frac yn.$$ We have thus shown that if $x>a,$ then there exists some $y>0$ and some natural $n\ge1$ such that $x\ge a+\frac yn.$ This is the contrapositive of the implication we wanted to prove, so we're done. $\Box$

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Apostol?

You cannot have $a < x$ and $x < a + {\frac yn}$ for every $n\geq1$ at the same time. If $a < x$, then there will be an $n_0$ big enough such that $\frac y{n_o}$ is almost zero and then $x > a + \frac y{n_0}$

Comment: yup, it is the Apostol